# Simplify java program using inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I'm currently learning inheritance in java. I have a superclass called Students with subclasses UndergradStudents & GraduateStudents. Both of them have a method called deansHonourList. In the undergrad deansHonourList method it checks if the GPA is greater than 3.5 to qualify for the deans list and for the graduate subclass the gpa has to be greater than 3.75, I have to remove the methods in the subclasses and create one method in the superclass that determines if the student qualifies for the deans honour list. Here is my code so far.

```
 import java.io.*;

public class Activity6C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[4];

        students[0] = new UndergradStudent(8032, "Casper", 2.78, 2);
        students[1] = new GraduateStudent(3044, "Sheena", 3.92, "Natural Language Processing");
        students[2] = new UndergradStudent(6170, "Yolanda", 4.26, 3);
        students[3] = new GraduateStudent(1755, "Geordi", 3.58, "Human-Computer Interaction");

        printStudents(students);
        printDeansList(students);

        System.out.println("\nEnd of processing.");
    }

    public static void printStudents(Student[] students) {
        System.out.println("\nList of all students:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + ": " + students[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void printDeansList(Student[] students) {
        System.out.println("\nDean's honour list:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            if (students[i].deansHonourList()) {
                System.out.println(students[i]);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 class Student {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(int number, String name, double gpa) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public boolean deansHonourList() {
        //Here is where i make my code to determine honour list students
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return number + " " + name + " (" + gpa + ")";
    }
 }

 class UndergradStudent extends Student {
    private int year;

    public UndergradStudent(int number, String name, double gpa, int year)   {
        super(number, name, gpa);
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean deansHonourList() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (getGPA() >= 3.5)
            result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Undergraduate: " + super.toString() + " year: " + year;
    }
 }

 class GraduateStudent extends Student {
    private String thesis;

    public GraduateStudent(int number, String name, double gpa, String       thesis) {
        super(number, name, gpa);
        this.thesis = thesis;
    }

    public boolean deansHonourList() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (getGPA() >= 3.75)
            result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Graduate: " + super.toString() + " thesis: " + thesis;
    }
 }
```

Note: This is an exercise and it's not worth much but I would like a hint in the right direction. Here is what the question also specifies.

I have to make it work without using instanceof or getClass(), and without adding any more if-else statements or instance variables. There should be no deansHonourList() method in either GraduateStudent or UndergraduateStudent, and the getGPA() method can be removed.

The hint i got was to add another instance method to the superclass and override it in the subclasses as necessary; call that method in your deansHonourList() method.

---

I can't think of a way to do this. I mean what can I put in the new instance method that I would make, and then override it in the subclasses.

Thank you for reading my question or any hints you are able to give me.

Comment: You're going to need another (possibly abstract) method which determines if the GPA is high enough based on the implementation of `Student`

Comment: After removing the deansHonorList method from the subclasses, I made it in the superclass. Then it says I can make another instance method in the superclass and override it in the subclasses and use the instance method inside the deansHonoutList method which also exists in the superclass. So the abstract method would be the new instance method you're talking about?

Comment: Hint: You have described all the steps you need to take in your question. But, you don't know *why*. So, before you think of *how* to do it, you have to know *what* you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a (possibly abstract) method which returns the minimum GPA score acceptable to be considered for the honours list, maybe something like

```
abstract class Student {

    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(int number, String name, double gpa) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public abstract double getMinimumHonourListGPA();

    public boolean deansHonourList() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (getGPA() >= getMinimumHonourListGPA()) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return number + " " + name + " (" + gpa + ")";
    }
}
```

Then you could implement doing something like...

```
class UndergradStudent extends Student {

    private int year;

    public UndergradStudent(int number, String name, double gpa, int year) {
        super(number, name, gpa);
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Undergraduate: " + super.toString() + " year: " + year;
    }

    @Override
    public double getMinimumHonourListGPA() {
        return 3.5;
    }
}
```

Now, if that's not acceptable, you will need to pass the minimum GPA score via the constructor to the parent class, something like...

```
class Student {

    private int number;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;
    private double minimumHonourListGPA;

    public Student(int number, String name, double gpa, double minimumHonourListGPA) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.minimumHonourListGPA;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public boolean deansHonourList() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (getGPA() >= minimumHonourListGPA) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return number + " " + name + " (" + gpa + ")";
    }
}

class UndergradStudent extends Student {

    private int year;

    public UndergradStudent(int number, String name, double gpa, int year) {
        super(number, name, gpa, 3.5);
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Undergraduate: " + super.toString() + " year: " + year;
    }
}
```

for example

Comment: This is very likely a school assignment, and OP is supposed to learn how to do it himself.

Comment: @Kenney Yes, it is likely homework, and I appreciate you desire for the OP to learn these things themselves, I agree. But the OP has made some head ground themselves and has asked for a hand, should we really ignore them or should we provide appropriate guidance where we can.  I thought the point of SO was to try and help people who had a need.  Hence the reason I've provide two possible solutions, to try and provide some form of learning to the approach, I'm sure there are other was to achieve the same result.  No one is an island and the development community is greater because people shared

Comment: @Kenney I mentioned that in the question if you haven't read it. I asked for a hint not for the solution. Thank you thou.

Comment: @MikeDavidson It's sometimes difficult to "describe" a solution which can be better demonstrated :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really appreciate your response. Thank you for taking the time out, and the first approach seems perfect for me. Again thank you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't see why you are suggesting I was implying we ignore OP. You don't have to defend helping people: we agree on that. We're just not agreeing on what constitutes "appropriate guidance" in this case, and we certainly don't have to. Your answer is what OP would have come up with by himself, given appropriate guidance. That way, something is learned, as his teacher intended. But none of this means that I appreciate you any less for being here, helping people.

Comment: @Kenney Had the OP dumped a requirement, without showing effort, I'd be with you 100%, no effort, no answer. The OP showed some effort and was stuck on where to go from there, inheritance was a complete pain for me to learn when I started learning OO (but then there weren't that many people who were available to help me not the resources available we have today). I felt a simple demonstration (with explanation) was more appropriate then a long winded description which loses meaning in translation. If you have links that would otherwise answer the OPs question, then I will delete this answer :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Again, I never suggested *"no effort, no answer"*. And, this is a pretty good answer, it's not that. Lately I've been wondering, an I really helping someone by doing their work for them? *"give a man a fish"*, and all. You know, I'm fine with this answer, and if something is learned, all the better!

Comment: @Kenney I suggest "no effort, no answer" ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I usually do "no effort? `[rtfm](link)`!" ;-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I created a method that initially suggests that the student is undergrad, and then in the grad subclass it overrides it to false. So in my superclass I have it so that if the the student is grad and the gpa is above 3.75 it will return true, else if the student is undergrad and the gpa is greater than 3.5 then it will also return true. If both those dont fall in the result is false. So it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what if you had a method 'requiredGPA()', which returned the GPA required to get on the Deans Honour List?

You would then override this method in the subclasses to return their different requirements, and the superclass's deansHonourList() would use the value returned from this method to decide if the student was on the list?

I could give a code example if needed... let me know if I haven't been clear in this answer?

Edit- looks like MadProgrammer has hit the idea I was going for here.

Comment: Thank you! MadProgrammer got me on this one. It's programmer like you guys that make me wan't to get into computer science. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of Facade design pattern.
Check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm).

This pattern is about providing a simple interface to hide the underlying complexity. Interface is used for the invocation of a single and during the run time JVM will determine which method to call. This method is determined by the implementing class of the object on which method was invoked.

In your case Student is going to work as the interface. As others suggested you can use an abstract class with abstract method **deansHonourList** or you can use an empty implementation.

Now suppose we have empty constructors in all three classes.

```
Student student1 = new Student();
Student student2 = new UnderGraduateStudent();
Student student3 = new GraduateStudent();
```

Since a parent class reference variable can hold instance of the child class we are able to assign objects of UnderGraduateStudent and GraduateStudent to the Student type reference variables.

All these three classes have method **deansHonourList**.
When we call this method on all the three objects as following

```
student1.deansHonourList(arguments...)
student2.deansHonourList(arguments...)
student3.deansHonourList(arguments...)
```

JVM will find the correct class from which it has to invoke the method by checking the type of the student1, student2, student3 instances.

Only one of these methods will be called (unlike constructor where super class constructor is called in subclass constructor).

Even if the deansHonourList is called on parent class reference, the method from the child class is called as the reference holds child class instance.
This is called **Method Overriding**.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) out.

Overriding only works in case of non static methods, in case of static methods, parent class methods are called. Since static members are part of the class not the class instance, instance plays no role in the method resolution.
This is called **Method Hiding**